# Ember.js - Error when running ember --version command

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I am trying to run an `ember.js` app on my laptop but after installing the `ember-cli` and trying to run `ember --version` command I get an `error`.

To install `ember-cli` I used the following command - `npm install -g ember-cli`

It is probably important to mention that when I run `ember --version` command outside of the app directory it works, but when I run it inside app directory it crashes and gives `error`.

`Node.js` version - `8.11.3`

This is the `error` that I get:

```
ember --version

/Users/user/go/src/github.com/apps/app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:85
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/go/src/github.com/apps/app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js:3:44)
```

As suggested in comments by Buck Doyle I changed `Node.js` version to `14.5.0` and ran `ember --version` command again, but I got a different error this time:

```
Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (83)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1


Stack Trace and Error Report: /var/folders/bt/p_dtgwnd23gbv8nc7v_wpzmr0000gn/T/error.dump.ddc14c42b05e40a5181262bd0b9ad027.log
```

Comment: Can you try a newer Node version? I suspect the version of Ember CLI installed is too new for Node 8.

Comment: @BuckDoyle I just tried Node version 14.5.0 but got a different error which you can see in my updated question. Something somewhere has dependency on node-sass@3.13.1 but this version of node-sass is supported by Node version < 7.6 I think.

Comment: You’ll have to change the version of `node-sass` as described by [this table](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page-below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimum-support)

Answer (score 1):

> It is probably important to mention that when I run ember --version command outside of the app directory it works, but when I run it inside app directory it crashes and gives error.

Just wanted to answer this small piece. When you run `ember` inside of a directory with a `package.json` that includes `ember-cli` it will run the version of ember installed there. This is really nice when you're moving between a few apps with different versions of `ember-cli`, but can be surprising in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

replace `catch` with `catch (error)`
just had the same problem and solved it by replacing catch with catch(error) so you need to add (error) next to each catch.
i needed to change this in about 10 files. so you gotta change every time and run it so you see the new location of the error. best of luck